# Difference between PCR for linear template and a plasmid?

Tags: dna, pcr, dna-replication

I believe PCR can be conducted both on a linear template and a plasmid, and I was wondering how these procedures differ in what enzymes are used, how the enzymes work on the template, primers used etc.

Answer (score 2):

There's not much difference between them. The same enzyme and condition can be used whether the template is circular or linear.

You can amplify plasmids, but PCR intrinsically generates linear DNA fragments even if you use circular DNAs.